# knitr - change output text color in Rstudio

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, knitr

I'm trying to use **knitr** to make my code available in PDF, for studying purposes.

Is there a way to have the **output text** in a **different color** from the one of the **code**?
I've seen some examples online and read older threads but I can't figure it out!
For example

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
knitr::opts_chunk$set(background='#faf7ed', character)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knit_theme$set("fruit")
@

<<>>=
example <- 2 + 2
example
@


\end{document}
```

When compiled to PDF produces:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPl5a.png)

I basically want to make the code

```
example <- 2 + 2
example
```

more easily distinguishable from the output

```
# [1] 4
```

by changing either one of the text or background colors; I don't want to change the overall background color, because it wouldn't be helpful.

If this isn't possible, how can I separate the two parts?

Any help is appreciated!

I tried changing themes, chunk background color

Comment: Can you show the intermediate .tex file?

Comment: I'm not sure I know how, knitting to a .tex file I just get a file with only \documentclass{article}

\begin{document}